# bidi string can't be read from Word (Apache POI)

Tags: java, apache-poi, bidi

I'm writing a bidi String to an MS Word file using Apache POI after wrapping it with the sequence
`aString = "\u202E" + aString + "\u202C";` 
The text renders correctly in the file, and reads fine when I retrieve the string again. But if I modify the file in anyway, suddenly, reading that string returns true with isBlank().
Thank you in advance for any suggestions/help!

Comment: How exactly are you reading from `Word`? Are you sure you read the correct text run? Sometimes `Word` splits text in text runs for very strange reasons. Sometimes there are empty text runs as well. If spell checking is enabled and text is in language which `Word` has not set for spell checking, then sometimes every single letter inclusive spaces will be in a separate text run. If you then get a text run containing a space only, then `String.isBlank()` will be true.

Comment: @AxelRichter, oh hi! it's you guided me to fix the encoding problem. And I did think of the multiple runs (and paragraphs) possibility. But calling getRuns().size() returns 1. The strange thing is that the string reads absolutely fine AS LONG AS I don't modify the MS Word file manually. One letter  and all the text written by the program becomes null. It exists and is visible from the file, but the program can't read it anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Microsoft Word` stores bidirectional text in it's `Office Open XML` `*.docx` format, then it sometimes uses special text run elements `w:bdo` (**b**i **d**irectional **orientation**). `Apache poi` does not read those elements until now. So if a `XWPFParagraph` contains such elements, then `paragraph.getText()` will return an empty string.

One could using `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor` to really get all text from all `XWPFParagraph`s like so:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;

public class ReadWordParagraphs {
    
 static String getAllTextFromParagraph(XWPFParagraph paragraph) {
  XmlCursor cursor =  paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
  return cursor.getTextValue();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordDocument.docx"));
  
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
   System.out.println(paragraph.getText()); // will not return text in w:bdo elements
   System.out.println(getAllTextFromParagraph(paragraph)); // will return all text content of paragraph
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! thank you!
Should I use XmlCursor to read strings and just stop using paragraph.getText() altogether?